# New here, using \pstree and want to put vertical dots between two edges

Tags: pst-tree

This is what I have so far. The vertical dots go beyond the two edges. I want them to end before they reach them.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{listing}
\usepackage{qtree}% For drawing trees.
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree,pstricks-add}%This might be better.
\title{Trees}

\author{G}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
{\pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=3.5]{\Tdot*[name=A] \taput{$\emptyset$}}{
\pstree[treemode=R, levelsep=3.5]{\Tdot*[name=B]\taput{$p_{1}$}}{%
  {\pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=3.5]{\Tdot*[name=C]\taput{$p_{1}$}}% %
        {\Tdot*[name=D]~{\dots}\taput{$p_{1}$} \Tdot*[name=E]~{\dots}\tbput{$p_{2}$}}}
  {\pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=3.5]{\Tdot*[name=F]\tbput{$p_{2}$}}% %
        {\Tdot*[name=G]~{\dots}\taput{$p_{1}$} \Tdot*[name=H]~{\dots}\tbput{$p_{2}$}}}}
\pstree[treemode=R, levelsep=3.5]{\Tdot*[name=I]\tbput{$p_{2}$}}{%\vdots
  {\pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=3.5]{\Tdot*[name=J]\taput{$p_{1}$}}% %
        {\Tdot*[name=K]~{\dots}\taput{$p_{1}$} \Tdot*[name=L]~{\dots}\tbput{$p_{2}$}}}
  {\pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=3.5]{\Tdot*[name=M]\tbput{$p_{2}$}}% %
        {\Tdot*[name=N]~{\dots}\taput{$p_{1}$} \Tdot*[name=P]~{\dots}\tbput{$p_{2}$}}}}
}}
\ncline[linestyle=dotted,nodesep=1.5mm,offset=1cm]{I}{B}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way. I removed unnecessary packages. Note it doesn't produce any result with `pdflatex` and `auto-pst-pdf`, but works with `xelatex` and, of course with `latex`:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{pst-tree,pstricks-add}%This might be better.
\title{Trees}

\author{G}

\date{\today}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\clearpage
\psset{treemode=R, levelsep=3.5}
\pstree{\Tdot*[name=A] \taput{$\varnothing$}}{%
    \pstree{\Tdot*[name=B]\taput{$p_{1}$}\ncput[npos=0.7]{\rnode{X}{}}}{%
        {\pstree{\Tdot*[name=C]\taput{$p_{1}$}}% %
            {\Tdot*[name=D]~{$ \cdots $}\taput{$p_{1}$} \Tdot*[name=E]~{$ \cdots $}\tbput{$p_{2}$}}}
        {\pstree{\Tdot*[name=F]\tbput{$p_{2}$}}% %
            {\Tdot*[name=G]~{$ \cdots $}\taput{$p_{1}$} \Tdot*[name=H]~{$ \cdots $}\tbput{$p_{2}$}}}}
    \pstree{\Tdot*[name=I]\tbput{$p_{2}$} \ncput[npos=0.7]{\rnode{Y}{}}}{%\vdots
        {\pstree{\Tdot*[name=J]\taput{$p_{1}$}}% %
            {\Tdot*[name=K]~{$ \cdots $}\taput{$p_{1}$} \Tdot*[name=L]~{$ \cdots $}\tbput{$p_{2}$}}}
        {\pstree{\Tdot*[name=M]\tbput{$p_{2}$}}% %
            {\Tdot*[name=N]~{$ \cdots $}\taput{$p_{1}$} \Tdot*[name=P]~{$ \cdots $}\tbput{$p_{2}$}}}}
}
\ncline[linestyle=dotted,nodesep=2pt]{X}{Y}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a **forest** version. Note that the actual tree specification is very concise:

```
  [
    [, tikz={
        \draw [dotted] ($()!1/3!(!u)$) -- ($(!s)!1/3!(!u)$);
      }
      [[][]]
      [[][]]
    ]
    [
      [[][]]
      [[][]]
    ]
  ]
```

The `tikz` bit is responsible for drawing the vertical dotted line.

Everything else is done in the specification of the style, including the setting of the labels, the customisation of nodes and spacing and the addition of the dots on the right.

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow=0,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum width=2.5pt,
    fill,
    draw,
    circle,
    s sep+=5pt,
    l+=15pt,
    if level=0{
      label={[font=\scriptsize]above:$\varnothing$}
    }{
      if n=1{
        edge label={node [below, midway, font=\scriptsize] {$p_2$} }
      }{
        edge label={node [above, midway, font=\scriptsize] {$p_1$} }
      }
    },
    if n children=0{
      append={[, l-=25pt, edge={dotted}]}
    }{}
  }
  [
    [, tikz={
        \draw [dotted] ($()!1/3!(!u)$) -- ($(!s)!1/3!(!u)$);
      }
      [[][]]
      [[][]]
    ]
    [
      [[][]]
      [[][]]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: auto-dots]